# Aerospike python client: check if records were stored on the cluster successfully

Tags: python, aerospike, aerospike-loader

I am working on Aerospike python client. I am inserting data into the cluster using aerospike loader. Now I need to see whether the records were stored on the cluster successfully.

The command being used:

```
command = 'java -cp /aerospike-loader/aerospike-load-2.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar ' \
              '-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/aerospike-loader/log4j.properties ' \
              'com.aerospike.load.AerospikeLoad -h %s -p %d -n %s -c %s %s'
command_str = command % (self.host, self.port, self.namespace, tmp_json_file.name, data_file_path)
```

the file `tmp_json_file` contains config file content exactly similar to this: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/asloader/examples.html

Now how do I check whether the data was transferred successfully? I tried using `client.exists(key)`, but the `meta` field returns `None` as `writePolicy=true` was not set. How to set that using python client any example? Or any other way to check that the records were successfully inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract all the keys from the JSON and for each assemble a tuple of `(namespace, json-set, json-key)` (I mean using the `set` and `key` fields of the each JSON object). You can then make use of [`aerospike.Client.exists_many`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#aerospike.Client.exists_many) to verify the existence of the keys using batch read operations.

Even if you didn't store the human-readable key (that's the default behavior and you probably don't want to spend the extra storage), each [record](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/data-model.html#records) has a unique 20B digest. That digest is created in the client by hashing the set and primary key part of the 3-tuple mentioned above. When you'll check for existence the client will once again hash those keys you gave it, getting the same digests, and check on their existence.